# Selecting multiple schemas in a select statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The db being accessed is on Snowflake; not certain on the storage details behind the scenes.

I have a query right now that creates a new view from 41 data tables stored in separate schemas under the same database, looks something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW all_data AS
SELECT * FROM db.schema1.data UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM db.schema2.data UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM db.schema3.data
```

This query is run daily. My issue is I get new data tables added every few days and I have to go manually edit the query to include those new tables, as they're stored under separate schemas (and the naming scheme for the schemas isn't consistent either, for reasons outside my control). Is there a way I can select all the schemas inside a database with a subquery that would allow me to run the query daily without needing manual updates when new schemas + tables are added?

I'd like the resulting query to have a structure somewhat like

```
CREATE VIEW all_data as 
SELECT * FROM [SELECT schemas from db].data
```

but not sure how that would work, and how to union the resulting data correctly.

Comment: you definitely need to tag your RDBMS for this one. sql-server? oracle? mysql?....  Also the answer for sql-server is NO you cannot create a view that will automatically select from dynamically identified schema's in that manner.  But you can create a stored procedure that uses dynamic sql to do it, or you can create a stored procedure to alter and recreate your view based upon the schemas that exist and just run that before running the query on the view.

Comment: It's running on snowflake, actually not sure what the back end is for that.

Comment: okay I think I tagged the right one but check it out.  Sorry I haven't used that particular platform so I won't be able to assist.

Comment: Appreciate the assistance, I'm not too familiar with the platform either

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in Snowflake you can't dynamically construct SQL statements (yet). You can of course do what you want to achieve via a script in one of the supported languages (e.g. Python, JS), by first finding all the schemas and then constructing a full SQL statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's what it looks like I'm going to do: wrap the query in a python script that can dynamically generate it

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely query the table and schema list available. SQL Authority has a good article on it:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/17/sql-server-list-schema-name-and-table-name-for-database/

In short the query winds up being along these lines to pull the list of tables and schema:

```
SELECT '['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'
AS SchemaTable
FROM sys.tables
```

Though you will have to add a database name to the where clause to point to the proper DB.

Comment: database name is not contained within the sys.tables system view!  if you want from a particular database that the connection is not already connected to then you would select from DBNAME.sys.tables instead. Also while this addresses how he can find the shema's it doesn't address how he can use it to modify his view or within his view to dynamically select the tables

Answer (score 0):

With the release of [Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html) dynamic recreation of the view inside Snowflake is now very possible.

```
create database dynamic_views;
create schema dynamic_views.schema_base;
create schema dynamic_views.schema1;
create table dynamic_views.schema1.data(id int) as select * from values (1);
```

We can use the [INFORMATION_SCEMA.TABLES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/tables.html) to find all `DATA` tables:

```
SELECT table_schema 
FROM dynamic_views.information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name = 'DATA';
```

| TABLE_SCHEMA |
| --- |
| SCHEMA1 |

and now push that into a cursor and build up a view creation SQL

This SQL needs to be run in the new Snowsight Console see ([Working with Classic Console](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html)):

```
declare
  sql text;
  add_union boolean := false;
  c1 cursor for SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA 
        FROM dynamic_views.information_schema.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DATA';
begin
  sql := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dynamic_views.schema_base.all_data AS ';
  for record in c1 do
    if (add_union) then
         sql := sql || 'UNION ALL ';
    end if;
    sql := sql || 'SELECT * FROM dynamic_views.'|| record.TABLE_SCHEMA ||'.data ';
    add_union := true;
  end for;
  
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql;
  return sql;
end;
;
```

and we can use it:

```
select * from dynamic_views.schema_base.all_data;
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |

and add more:

```
create schema dynamic_views.schema2;
create table dynamic_views.schema2.data(id int) as select * from values (2);
```

rebuild:

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dynamic_views.schema_base.all_data AS SELECT * FROM dynamic_views.SCHEMA1.data UNION ALL SELECT * FROM dynamic_views.SCHEMA2.data |

use it again:

```
select * from dynamic_views.schema_base.all_data;
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

*Note:* You should not use `SELECT *` in production as the order of the table columns will be dependent of the create orders, and if newer tables have a different shape you view will become invalid.

So the explicit form really should be used:

```
'SELECT column1, column2, column4 FROM dynamic_views.'|| record.TABLE_SCHEMA ||'.data ';
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who want the solution for this question this is my Idea with useing FETCH

```
Declare @str nvarchar(maX)
 Declare @i int 
 Set @i =(Select max(id ) from Clinics );
set @str='';
declare @Id int
 declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
    select  [Id]  from  [dbo].[Clinics]    
    GROUP BY [Id]
open cur
fetch next from cur into @Id
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
if @i>@id 
    begin
set @str=@str+ 'sELECT '+ LTRIM(RTRIM(Convert(varchar(6),@Id))) + ',* fROM ' + quotename(LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),@Id))))+'.[Clinic_Benefits] UNION ALL ';
end
else
begin
set @str=@str+ 'sELECT '+ LTRIM(RTRIM(Convert(varchar(6),@Id))) + ',* fROM ' + quotename(LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),@Id))))+'.[Clinic_Benefits]  ';
end
fetch next from cur into @Id
END
close cur
deallocate cur
print @str;
exec (@str);
```